# How do I change the transport for remote drush alias calls

Tags: drush

We're moving to an environment where our drupal instances will live inside docker containers managed by kubernetes.

Currently I've got scripts for things like checking module security status across large numbers of drupal sites.  Basically I maintain a file full of aliases, and I iterate over those.  It works well enough.

With the move to kubernetes, what I'd like to happen is that my aliases would somehow specify that the way to call the remote instance is via a kubectl command that effectively invokes drush in the remote container.  It looks a lot like an alternative to ssh as the transport.

1. Is something like this possible?
2. OK, so I've got the source code, and anything is presumably possible, but what might a sensible approach look like?  What should I look at to get my head around this?

Comment: did you come up with any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you currently can't change the transport / replace SSH. However, most of the work can be fixed be writing wrapper scripts. Read https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2367